# Migration from ES 6.8 to 7.17 : Issues with negative date epoch timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch

We are migrating our applications from 6.8 ES cluster to 7.17.10 ES cluster . The one thing which we identified is that the negative values are not supported for date type fields( "format": "epoch_millis") . Is there any way to make it support in 7.17.10 ? because we see this PR to support this https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/80208 which looks like fixed in ES 8.XX versions . Can someone guide me how we can resolve this issue . we can't change the data type of this field . Also is there any way in ES to lets say disable template validation specific to one field . Please suggest which is the better way to handle this issue ?